# What is the height of the dewalt dw745 table saw on compact stand?

Tags: table-saw

I am thinking about purchasing the dewalt dw745 (type 20) table saw with the compact stand included. When on the stand, what is the table top height? I haven’t found much info online with regards to total height from floor to table top.  I’ll be building a larger table to cut larger boards so with any luck I will be able to get my table flush with the dw745. 
[image: dw745 saw height]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. Do you intend to build this into a permanent station for workshop use or will the saw go on the road? From what I've seen worksite saws with integrated stand have one height — too low :-)

Comment: Seriously though, like with workbenches, comfortable/safe working level depends on individual height and guys taller than average like me will find 'normal' heights a bit low but someone of average height probably won't. Responders here (and elsewhere if you also ask the same question on a forum) will be able to help you better if you say how tall you are in addition to how you intend to use the saw. You can edit your Question here as many times as needed to add more information.

Comment: The internet tells us the compact stand is 20in high, for about 33in total tool height.

Comment: If you are building a larger table then why use the stand and all ?  Build a drop down space in your larger table to the height you need or  a sturdy shop stand and save the compact stand for when you do work away from the shop.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give an exact height; those stands usually end up being a pretty 'normal' (if there is such a thing!) height.

What I'd strongly suggest, though, is that you design your bench at the height you want, and simply drop the saw into a big hole in the top of it. Among other things, that will ensure that you can make the saw dead flush with the top, and make it extremely solid within the table. (Otherwise, the stand would be squirming around, and doing fine adjustments on the height is near impossible.)